# Will my EBS volume in my EBS backed EC2 instance persist?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

So I have setup a server on Amazon Web Services EC2 with an EBS backed volume.  It will act as an SVN server so I will certainly want the EBS volume to be persistent.

The scenario I have in mind is say the EC2 instance dies for whatever reason, I can just boot up another EC2 instance with that same EBS which will have all the data it had up until the previous EC2 instance crashed

I did some reading and it says when the server terminates, it will also delete the EBS volume attached to it.  Does this mean if say it crashes, or the host machine goes down will I lose the EBS volume?

If yes, then what do I need to do to ensure my EBS volume remains even though the EC2 instance it was attached to as root device is no longer around?

FYI, all I've done at this point is created an instance from the Amazon Linux AMI with EBS, and set it up the instance as necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the "Delete on Termination" setting for your instance to keep an EBS volume even if your instance gets terminated. If you are using the command line tool, you can use the ec2-modify-instance-attribute --block-device-mapping command. Here is a link to Amazon's documentation on this subject. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ModifyInstanceAttribute.html?r=4426

Comment: thanks!  A little bit of an aside, but if my instance say crashes or Amazon has hardware failure, does my instance go into stop or terminated?

Comment: If it crashes, it will likely stay in the running state until you stop and start it from the console/API, as a crash is probably from the OS level. As for hardware failure, the Amazon page on EBS can give you a little more information regarding your options. http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/

Comment: Usually when there is a hardware failure, you can also use Nikanoru's suggestion of stopping and starting, which will detect the hardware failure and switch to different hardware automatically. Note that in this case reboot will not have this effect, you must stop, and then start in order to switch hardware. Also note that there is a special status with code 272 that typically signifies a hardware issue.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the correct answer from @Nikanoru, make sure you *practice* restoring from an EBS snapshot once or twice, and *write down* the procedure.

The worst time to start sorting out the details is when your website is down.

Also, ensure that you take snapshots after any change you would not want to lose.

Comment: We have also learned the hard way that occasionally EBS instances "can be lost"...